# Scikit-learn(Python) Different metric results(f1 score) for StratifiedKFold

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

I want to find the best split for my StratifiedKFold and build my model on the best split .The code is as follows:

```
def best_classifier(clf,k,x,y):

    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=k,shuffle=True)

    bestclf = None
    bestf1 = 0
    bestsplit = []
    cnt = 1
    totalf1 = 0

    for train_index,test_index in skf.split(x,y):
        x_train,x_test = x[train_index],x[test_index]
        y_train,y_test = y[train_index],y[test_index]
        clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
        predicted_y = clf.predict(x_test)
        f1 = f1_score(y_test,predicted_y)
        totalf1 = totalf1+f1
        print(y_test.shape)

        print(cnt," iteration f1 score",f1)
        if cnt==10:
            avg = totalf1/10
             print(avg)
        if f1>bestf1:
            bestf1 = f1
            bestclf = clf
            bestsplit = [train_index,test_index]

        cnt = cnt+1   
    return [bestclf,bestf1,bestsplit]
```

This function returns me an array of my classifier(fitted for the best split),best f1score and the indices of the best split

I call it as follows:

```
best_of_best = best_classifier(sgd,10,x_selected,y)
```

Now since i capture the best split and my classifier I once again test it for the same split just to check whether I am getting the same result as i got within the function.But apparently it is not so.
Code:

```
bestclf=  best_of_best[0]
test_index = best_of_best[2][1]
x_cv = x_selected[test_index]
y_cv = y[test_index]
pred_cv = bestclf.predict(x_cv)
f1_score(y_cv,pred_cv)
```

Results when the method is best_classifier is called:

```
(679,)
1  iteration f1 score 0.643298969072
(679,)
2  iteration f1 score 0.761750405186
(678,)
3  iteration f1 score 0.732773109244
(678,)
4  iteration f1 score 0.632911392405
(678,)
5  iteration f1 score 0.74179743224
(678,)
6  iteration f1 score 0.749140893471
(677,)
7  iteration f1 score 0.750830564784
(677,)
8  iteration f1 score 0.756756756757
(677,)
9  iteration f1 score 0.682170542636
(677,)
10  iteration f1 score 0.63813229572
0.708956236151
```

Result when I predict outside the best split of statifiedkfold

```
0.86181818181818182
```

As we can see that this f1 score is not observed in  the 10 folds .Why is it so?Am i doing something wrong?Is my logic of the method wrong?

Comment: Without knowing too much about sklearn StratifiedKFold i think the `shuffle=True` shuffles the data before each `skf.split`. How does it look if you set it to False? You could also keep `shuffle=True` and set `random_state = 1` to achieve the same shuffle each iteration.

Comment: Nope tried it but didn't work. Even though I set shuffle=True I capture my split indices for each shuffle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.The problem was because I was not deepcopying my clf object to bestclf. Every time when the Kth fold used to run my bestclf reference changed to current clf since i was not deep copying .

```
bestclf = copy.deepcopy(clf)
```